# javascript pushState problem with redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on index page (index.php) that when you click it, it should take you to other page (login.php) without reloading the page simultaneously. Below is javascript with pushState.

```
document.getElementById('cta_btn').onclick = function() {
window.history.pushState('', '', 'login.php');
};
```

The problem is that I stay on same page (index.php) only url changes /login.php

Answer (score 0):

`pushState` is a way of saying "I am using JavaScript to modify the DOM of this page so that it becomes the same as what you would get if you requested this URL". You don't appear to have written the JS to modify the DOM.

It **doesn't** cause new content to load by itself. It doesn't really navigate anywhere. It just pretends to so you can hook into `popstate` and change the DOM back to how it was before when the back button is pushed.

If you use `pushState` then you all need to change the DOM (with `createElement` and friends for simple cases and with frameworks like React for complex ones).

If you want to navigate to a new page, then assign a value to `location.href`.

If you don't want to load content from the server in order to do that navigation then make sure the user has previously visited the page and that [caching headers were sent then](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Answer (score -1):

I guess State is a Object, You should try this...
window.history.pushState({}, '', 'login.php');

Comment: There's no point in pushing an empty object into the state. It contains no more information than an empty string does when it is popped out of the state later. It certainly won't cause the page content to change **due** to the call to `pushState` (which is what the question is asking for).